# How to parse txt-file using REGEXP_SUBSTR in oracle?

Tags: regex, oracle, parsing, plsql, substring

I have got a lot of txt cards with same format.
And I need parse it to get some values from them.
I don't understand how use regexp substr in Oracle. Please, Help me write sql statements, which return values, which I marked between **-symbols (for example: first string, 02/02/11, AA11223344 and etc):

```
From: "abc def (**first string**)" <email@site.com>
02/01/2011  09:27                                    First Date  : **02/02/11**
Player  : BILL BROWN                                 ID          : **AA11223344**
At      : YELLOW STREET.                             CD Number   : **A11223FER**
                                                     Code        :          
BUYS    : **123M**          (M) of AAA 0 02/02/11        Owner       : **England**
                                                     Shiped      : **02/04/11**
Number  : **11.223344**     Digi     : **1.2370000**
Ddate:  **02/04/11**
Notes     : **First line here**
* Size       :                                            **USD 11,222,333.44** 
* Own ( **0 days** ):                                                    **0.00** 
* Total      :                                            USD **222,333,444.55**
```

Comment: Need more info and clarification.  Define "txt card".  Do you mean your sample data as shown is in one column of a table?  If so, is it multi-line or really one big line? Are expected values ALWAYS present or is there a chance it could be blank (NULL)?

Comment: Oh and edit the post to show exact expected output based on your example input.

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively apply regexp evaluation by using [hierarchical queries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm); at each level, you look for the level-th occurrence in your string.

Please pay attention to the "non greedy" operator (??) in pattern string, explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_regexp.htm), as well as regular expression functions.

```
with test as (
    select 'From: "abc def (**first string**)" <email@site.com>
            02/01/2011  09:27                                    First Date  : **02/02/11**
            Player  : BILL BROWN                                 ID          : **AA11223344**
            At      : YELLOW STREET.                             CD Number   : **A11223FER**
                                                                 Code        :          
            BUYS    : **123M**          (M) of AAA 0 02/02/11        Owner       : **England**
                                                                 Shiped      : **02/04/11**
            Number  : **11.223344**     Digi     : **1.2370000**
            Ddate:  **02/04/11**
            Notes     : **First line here**
            * Size       :                                            **USD 11,222,333.44** 
            * Own ( **0 days** ):                                                    **0.00** 
            * Total      :                                            USD **222,333,444.55** ' as txt
from dual
)
select TRIM('*' FROM regexp_substr(txt, '\*\*(.*??)\*\*', 1, LEVEL, 'n') ) 
from test
    CONNECT BY regexp_subSTR(txt, '\*\*(.*??)\*\*', 1, LEVEL, 'n') is not null
```

Comment: The OP stated that he had marked the input with `**` characters; so I don't think these are normally present but are included so we can see what the expected extraction values are.

Comment: I completely misunderstood the question. So, it's not that clear to me what behaviour the OP really needs